# tableView initwithframe and storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add a `tableview` as subview to my `tableViewController`, but I want to setup the cells in `storyboard`. It will be a static `tableview`.

This is the code for calling the `tableview` on button click.

```
- (IBAction)botaoAdicionar:(id)sender {
    AtividadesPraticadasTableView *tableview = [[AtividadesPraticadasTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 320) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:tableview];
}
```

In the `tableview` class I have this:

```
@implementation AtividadesPraticadasTableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, I have a `viewcontroller`in storyboard with  a `tableview`, which the class of the `tableview`I changed to this file `AtividadesPraticadasTableView`. It has three static custom cells in `storyboard`, therefore it opens a blank default `tableview`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static table views are entirely contained within the storyboard, and require information from the storyboard to display their content.

You've defined a static table view controller in the storyboard, populated it and set the tableView's custom class to your custom class, but when you want to add the table view you are just instantiating a table view of that class. That isn't going to get any of the information you've added to the storyboard.

In addition, the static cells information is read and understood by the *UITableViewController*, not the *UITableView*, so you are at the wrong level there too.

You need to do the following:

- Get a reference to the storyboard, either from your original view controller's `storyboard` property (if it is on the same storyboard as your static table) or using `storyboardWithName:bundle:`.
- instantiate the table view controller from that storyboard, using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. This will create a table view controller object containing all your static cells
- Add this as a child view controller to your original view controller, using `addChildViewController:`
- Add the table view controller's `tableView` as a subview

It may be simpler to add a container view in the storyboard to hold this view, and reveal it when the button is pressed, as Mike Slutsky suggested - this will do all of the instantiating and adding and child view controller-ing work for you, but the principle is still the same.

Also, adding a table view as a subview to a table view controller sounds very dodgy - a table view controller already has a table view as its view, and you can't really add subviews to that.

Comment: Thanks, @jrturton. it worked. The only thing is that I was trying to do it without having to instantiate a new `tableViewController`, that's why I was creating .h and .m files for `UITableView`instead. But is working now, great answer, as always.

Answer (score 1):

The thing your missing is the association between the programatically instantiated `tableview` and the `UITableView` that you put in your storyboard. You cannot just draw `UITableViews` in your storyboard and start instantiating new `UITableViews` in the controller's code and expect xcode to know which `UITableView` you wanted to use from the storyboard. Use an IBOutlet to connect a global variable for the controller to the `UITableView` in the storyboard, then the controller will know what you're trying to refer to. If you want that `UITableView` to appear on a button click, simply set the `UITableView` to hidden by default in the storyboard and then unhide it when the button is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

The thing You are missing called manual. Check this protocol for TableView dataSource https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource

P.S. Here good tutorial for storyboards http://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/xcode-4-storyboard

Comment: From my understanding, static `tableviews`shouldn't have `dataSource` methods. That's why I'm not using them.

Comment: I could use these methods to setup the cells programatically, that's not what I am trying to do. I want to setup the cells using `storyboard`.

Comment: Can I ask one stupid question? How long You work with objective C? I know that some beginners trying to use more of graphic interface than write code. This is not bad but them do not understand logik of their work.

Comment: I am trying to learn, you got that right, but you are getting out of focus and you are not really helping. Your answer does not apply to my question. But thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html - direct link